# 3-way thick wire connector (8-10awg wires)

Tags: connector, wire-terminals

What is a reliable, easy-to-use, and inexpensive 3-way connector for 8-10 awg or 5.5-8.5mm2 wires? 
Most 3-way connectors such as the one in the image below are too small to fit two 8-10awg wires in one side.
[image: image of small butt splice]
So far I have t-spliced 8-10awg wires using solder and heat shrink, but I am looking for a more reliable and durable solution.

Comment: Umm... what could be "more reliable and durable" than permanent solder!?

Comment: @Maple Something that does not melt at high fault currents, causing the wires to disconnect, flailing around inside and splashing molten metal all over the rest of the electronics.

Comment: @pipe: There are standards (IPC or otherwise) that explain in great detail how to do such a splice such that the connection does NOT come apart under the fault conditions that you mention.  The most common technique is to interleave the strands (push one wire into the other such that the strands go in-between the strands from the other side), then wrap the entire joint with thin wire (we use 30 AWG).  Then apply solder, ensuring that the entire joint area is filled.  In other words, what I described is one version of a lap joint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are "multiway" crimp butt connectors designed to accept two wires at one end and one at the other. For example, [these](http://www.jttproducts.com/in-line-multi-wire-butt-connectors-heat-shrink-crimp-seal.aspx) ones.

[image]

Called "In-line, Multi Wire Butt Connectors, Heat Shrink, Crimp Seal", they have heat shrink insulation with adhesive to seal the crimp joint.

Their largest size will accept 2x AWG 10 to 1x AWG 8 wires.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of crimp terminals on the market for 6-12AWG wires, for example two-sided InsulKrimp, Perma-Seal, NylaKrimp and single-sided 19160 series from Molex.

They are cheap and the crimping tool for them is not very expensive either. Basically, you had right idea but did not do your research. You can find all you need in electrical isle of any automotive store.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the room for DIN-rail connectors, Phoenix makes a series of spring-cage connectors that accept one conductor on one side and two conductors on the other side.  Crimp ferrules onto the conductors, then insert into the terminal block.

I specified exactly this configuration for a couple of installations some while back: two #10 wires coming into the enclosure and one #10 wire leaving.  The Phoenix representative explained that their spring-cage terminal blocks combined with ferrules on the conductors was a solution that would be reliable for decades.

The specific Phoenix connectors that were used for these jobs is linked below.  They accept conductor sizes from 8 AWG through 20 AWG.  Stranded conductors require ferrules.

[Feed-through terminal block - PT 6-TWIN - 3211929](https://www.phoenixcontact.com/online/portal/ca?uri=pxc-oc-itemdetail:pid=3211929&library=caen&tab=1)